# Поиск всех массивов на php по значению и вывод найденных массивов

Tags: php, json, foreach, decode

Всем привет.
Ребята, сразу не ругайтесь. Нужна помощь.
Есть json типа

```
{
    "status": "ok",
   "timestamp": 1541078845094,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 61,
            "fields": {
                "contract.id": 7,
                "date": 1534941334000,
                "amountType.id": 101291,
                "amountType.name": "Основная",
                "actionType.id": 101021,
                "actionType.name": "Начисление",
                "paymentType.id": 101172,
                "totalAmount.local": 3000000,
                "document.id": 28,
                "realDate": 1540557344563
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 65,
            "fields": {
                "contract.id": 7,
                "date": 1536842172808,
                "amountType.id": 101292,
                "amountType.name": "Процент",
                "actionType.id": 101021,
                "actionType.name": "Начисление",
                "paymentType.id": 101173,
                "totalAmount.local": 277000,
                "document.id": 30,
                "realDate": 1540557372857
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 66,
            "fields": {
                "contract.id": 7,
                "date": 1537792593094,
                "amountType.id": 101292,
                "amountType.name": "Процент",
                "actionType.id": 101021,
                "actionType.name": "Начисление",
                "paymentType.id": 101173,
                "totalAmount.local": 138500,
                "document.id": 31,
                "realDate": 1540557393120
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 67,
            "fields": {
                "contract.id": 7,
                "date": 1537879002218,
                "amountType.id": 101292,
                "amountType.name": "Процент",
                "actionType.id": 101021,
                "actionType.name": "Начисление",
                "paymentType.id": 101173,
                "totalAmount.local": 13850,
                "document.id": 32,
                "realDate": 1540557402255
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 68,
            "fields": {
                "contract.id": 7,
                "date": 1537879002218,
                "amountType.id": 101298,
                "amountType.name": "Штраф за опоздание",
                "actionType.id": 101021,
                "actionType.name": "Начисление",
                "paymentType.id": 101173,
                "totalAmount.local": 300,
                "document.id": 33,
                "realDate": 1540557402287
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 69,
            "fields": {
                "contract.id": 7,
                "date": 1540384612793,
                "amountType.id": 101292,
                "amountType.name": "Процент",
                "actionType.id": 101021,
                "actionType.name": "Начисление",
                "paymentType.id": 101173,
                "totalAmount.local": 401650,
                "document.id": 34,
                "realDate": 1540557412889
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 71,
            "fields": {
                "contract.id": 7,
                "date": 1540471012793,
                "amountType.id": 101298,
                "amountType.name": "Штраф за опоздание",
                "actionType.id": 101021,
                "actionType.name": "Начисление",
                "paymentType.id": 101173,
                "totalAmount.local": 300,
                "document.id": 35,
                "realDate": 1540557412933
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 70,
            "fields": {
                "contract.id": 7,
                "date": 1540471012793,
                "amountType.id": 101292,
                "amountType.name": "Процент",
                "actionType.id": 101021,
                "actionType.name": "Начисление",
                "paymentType.id": 101173,
                "totalAmount.local": 12590.91,
                "document.id": 34,
                "realDate": 1540557412901
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 77,
            "fields": {
                "contract.id": 7,
                "date": 1540557470000,
                "amountType.id": 1012915,
                "amountType.name": "Предоплата по процентам",
                "actionType.id": 1010211,
                "actionType.name": "Предоплата",
                "paymentType.id": 101172,
                "totalAmount.local": 12900,
                "document.id": 38,
                "realDate": 1540557500140
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 75,
            "fields": {
                "contract.id": 7,
                "date": 1540557470000,
                "amountType.id": 101298,
                "amountType.name": "Штраф за опоздание",
                "actionType.id": 101022,
                "actionType.name": "Погашение",
                "paymentType.id": 101172,
                "totalAmount.local": 300,
                "document.id": 37,
                "realDate": 1540557500005
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 73,
            "fields": {
                "contract.id": 7,
                "date": 1540557470000,
                "amountType.id": 101298,
                "amountType.name": "Штраф за опоздание",
                "actionType.id": 101022,
                "actionType.name": "Погашение",
                "paymentType.id": 101172,
                "totalAmount.local": 300,
                "document.id": 37,
                "realDate": 1540557499939
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 76,
            "fields": {
                "contract.id": 7,
                "date": 1540557470000,
                "amountType.id": 101292,
                "amountType.name": "Процент",
                "actionType.id": 101022,
                "actionType.name": "Погашение",
                "paymentType.id": 101172,
                "totalAmount.local": 415500,
                "document.id": 37,
                "realDate": 1540557500028
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 74,
            "fields": {
                "contract.id": 7,
                "date": 1540557470000,
                "amountType.id": 101292,
                "amountType.name": "Процент",
                "actionType.id": 101022,
                "actionType.name": "Погашение",
                "paymentType.id": 101172,
                "totalAmount.local": 415500,
                "document.id": 37,
                "realDate": 1540557499968
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 72,
            "fields": {
                "contract.id": 7,
                "date": 1540557470000,
                "amountType.id": 101292,
                "amountType.name": "Процент",
                "actionType.id": 101021,
                "actionType.name": "Начисление",
                "paymentType.id": 101173,
                "totalAmount.local": 12590.91,
                "document.id": 36,
                "realDate": 1540557493266
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Как найти все массивы, в которых `"amountType.id" = 101292` , чтобы в дальнейшем добавить их в excel через PHPExcel?

Пытаюсь вывести через

```
$responseJson = "$response"; 
$response3 = json_decode($responseJson, true);
$response4 = $response3['data'];

$needle = 101022;

foreach($response4 as $t){
    if($t['fields']['actionType.id'] == $needle){
        $result = $t;
        if (strpos($t['fields']['actionType.id'], '101022') !== true) // именно через жесткое сравнение
        {
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($result);
            echo "</pre>";
        }
        break;
    }
print_r($result);

}
```

Да, в курсе, что там 2 методы добавил, но пытаюсь уже разными способами. Кучу времени на это убил.
Глупый гугл не даёт нужного ответа, до 100 страницы дошёл.
Хелп братцы.

Comment: Ну выведите `$t['fields']['actionType.id']`, посмотрите чего в нем.

Comment: Он выводит только один из многих. Тут, наверно, надо уточнить, что количество массивов может быть разное. Но структура одна и та же.

При выводе $t['fields']['actionType.id'] получаю 101022

Comment: Ну и что там? Значения какие?

Comment: А при выводе $result получаю один массив(с нужным значением, но один)
Причем они меняются, то 75, то 74, то 76

Comment: `$result[] = $t` вам надо, а то вы просто заменяете массив, а не добавляете элемент

Comment: и не ясно зачем вы там `strpos` используете, если у вас там числа. просто сравните их да и все.

Comment: teran, я, к моему стыду уже разными способами пробовал, не могу понять, где моя ошибка.

Comment: Попробовал сделать так foreach($response4 as $t){
  foreach($response4 as $t){
    if($t['fields']['actionType.id'] == $needle){
        $result[] = $t;
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($result);
        echo "</pre>";
        break;
    }

}
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($result);
            echo "</pre>";
        }
        break;
    }

}

Тоже выводит только 1 массив. =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php)

```
$needle = 101292;
$result = array_filter($arr['data'], function($v) use ($needle){
                 return $v['fields']['amountType.id'] == $needle;
             });
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромнейшее!!!
Это действительно работает.
Вы супергерой! Так долго мучался.
Спасибо ещё раз ) Добрейшего Вам вечера.